# TypeScript + Dojo + AMD?

Tags: dojo, typescript, amd

Any examples of using AMD with TypeScript and dojo AMD?  Keep getting "3" instead of an object (tslab == 3):

```
    require( ["TypeScriptLab"], function ( tslab )
    {
        new tslab.Tests().run();
    } );
```

The TypeScript looks like this:

```
export class TypeScriptLab {
    test() {
    }
}
```

The generated JS looks like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var TypeScriptLab = (function () {
        function TypeScriptLab() { }
        TypeScriptLab.prototype.test = function () {
        };
        return TypeScriptLab;
    })();
    exports.TypeScriptLab = TypeScriptLab;    
})
```

Comment: Neglected to mention I'm using dojo 1.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined my packages:

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [
            { name: "TSLab", location: "/IPS" }
        ]
    };
</script>
```

And added a namespace prefix:

```
    require( ["TSLab/typeScriptLab"], function ( tslab )
    {
        new tslab.Tests().run();
    } );
```

And the module now loads.